# Inverse of Burrows-Wheeler

Tags: algorithms, strings

We can invert the Burrows-Wheeler with this method:

> The inverse can be understood this way. Take the final table in the
>   BWT algorithm, and erase all but the last column. Given only this
>   information, you can easily reconstruct the first column. The last
>   column tells you all the characters in the text, so just sort these
>   characters alphabetically to get the first column. Then, the first and
>   last columns (of each row) together give you all pairs of successive
>   characters in the document, where pairs are taken cyclically so that
>   the last and first character form a pair. Sorting the list of pairs
>   gives the first and second columns. Continuing in this manner, you can
>   reconstruct the entire list. Then, the row with the "end of file"
>   character at the end is the original text.

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform

I don't understand why this method works.

Comment: Find a source which contains a proof.

Comment: A source that I founded uses LF mapping which I understad. I don't understand the method in wikipedia.